# Android - Default background for navigation ImageButton

Tags: android, background, android-toolbar

What is the default background that is being used in the ImageButton (Hamburger button/ Logo button) in **android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar** ?

I am defining my custom Context Action bar, and i would like the background of my ImageButtons to be the same as the one is being used by the ImageButton in android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar.

I did try to use:

```
android:background="?android:attr/actionBarItemBackground"
```

and

```
android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
```

But both do not have the same effect onPressed as the default one.

How can i check what background is being used in the native one, or does anyone know what is the default background attribute being used?

Answer (score 0):

For changing the default overflow icon you can define a style like this:

```
<style name="AppTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="actionOverflowButtonStyle">@style/OverFlow</item>
</style>

<style name="OverFlow" parent="Widget.AppCompat.ActionButton.Overflow">
    <item name="android:src">@drawable/my_overflow_menu</item>
</style>
```

If you would like to change the color of the icon you can use:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
  app:theme="@style/ThemeToolbar" />


<style name="ThemeToolbar" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">

   <!-- navigation icon color -->
   <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/my_color</item>

    <!-- color of the menu overflow icon -->
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/my_color</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Im implementing my custom Context Action Bar, and i have some buttons on it, but when i press the button the highlighted color is different. I don't know what color is used in default Logo from toolbar, but i would use the same for my custom ImageButton inside my Custom Context Action Bar.

Comment: What i need to know is the background value that android is using for the default android.R.id.home icon. I tried to use: selectableItemBackground and actionBarItemBackground, but none of them are the same as the one used by native android toolbar.